# Openshift online v3 startup error

Tags: java, tomcat, openshift

I'm migrating my application from openshift online 2 to 3. This aplication is a tomcat war aplication, and relies on server.xml to load configuration. I already put in gihub configuration folder this but when the aplication deploys gives me the following error:

```
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [Connector[HTTP/1.1-auto-1]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: The connector cannot start since the specified port value of [-1] is invalid
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.startInternal(Unknown Source)
    ... 12 more
```

The server.xml is:

```
<Server port="-1" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">  
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener" SSLEngine="on" />
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.JasperListener" />
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.JreMemoryLeakPreventionListener" />
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.mbeans.GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener" />
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.ThreadLocalLeakPreventionListener" />

  <!-- Global JNDI resources
       Documentation at /docs/jndi-resources-howto.html
  -->
  <GlobalNamingResources>
    <!-- Editable user database that can also be used by
         UserDatabaseRealm to authenticate users
    -->
    <Resource name="UserDatabase" auth="Container"
              type="org.apache.catalina.UserDatabase"
              description="User database that can be updated and saved"
              factory="org.apache.catalina.users.MemoryUserDatabaseFactory"
              pathname="conf/tomcat-users.xml" />
  </GlobalNamingResources>
  <Service name="Catalina">  
    <Connector address="${OPENSHIFT_JBOSSEWS_IP}"
               port="${OPENSHIFT_JBOSSEWS_HTTP_PORT}"
               protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="200000"
               redirectPort="8443"/>

    <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost">

      <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.LockOutRealm">
        <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm"
               resourceName="UserDatabase"/>
      </Realm>

      <Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps"
            unpackWARs="false" autoDeploy="true">  
      <Valve
          className="org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteIpValve"
          protocolHeader="x-forwarded-proto"
        />

  <Valve 
    className="org.apache.catalina.valves.StuckThreadDetectionValve"
    threshold="60" />

      </Host>
    </Engine>
  </Service>
</Server>
```

and I added the environment variables OPENSHIFT_JBOSSEWS_IP to 0.0.0.0 and OPENSHIFT_JBOSSEWS_HTTP_PORT 8080.

What I'm missing or doing wrong?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already figure it out (with the help of openshift support). So my mistake was
instead using

```
<Server port="-1" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">
```

I should have

```
<Server port="8005" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">
```

and configure all the openshift environment variables